# mapping the model and fetching the user data

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

EDIT: Added more information.

I do have a `FirestoreHelper` class and contains a function called `readAll` that I call to fetch all users data.

```
class FirestoreHelper {
  static Stream<List<UserActivityModel>> readAll(String collectionPath, String subCollectionPath) {
    // get the main-collection path --- "user_activities"
    final mainCollection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(collectionPath);
    // read all docs.
    final mainDoc = mainCollection.doc();
    // get the sub-collection path --- "posts"
    final subcollection = mainDoc.collection(subCollectionPath).snapshots();

    // Unique Generated UUID
    return subcollection.map((querySnapshot) => querySnapshot.docs.map((e) => UserActivityModel.fromSnapshot(e)).toList());
  }
}
```

and I am calling that class function in my stream builder to fetch the data.
However I am encountering error, the stream falls under the `snapshot.data!.isEmpty` and whenver I print it it says `snapshot.data: 0`. Upon checking I do have documents in the `posts` sub-collection so I am confused why it says `empty or 0`.

```
StreamBuilder<List<UserActivityModel>>(
  stream: FirestoreHelper.readAll("user_activities", "posts"),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
      return const Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
      );
    } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
      return const Center(
        child: Text("An error has occured while fetching users posts."),
      );
    } else if (snapshot.data!.isEmpty) {
      // this prints "snapshot.data: 0".
      print("snapshot.data: ${snapshot.data?.length}");
      return Container(
          color: Colors.white,
          child: const Center(
            child: Text(
              "No posts/images posted by users...",
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            ),
          ));
    } else {
        // this is where the codes wherein the data should be applied
    }
```

and the overview of my Firebase Firestore structure is:

```
- user_activities(main collection)
  - user_uids(main document)
    - posts(sub collection)
      - random generated id(sub document)
      - fields are here that I want to collect.
```

I'd greatly appreciate anyone's help to solve this problem. Thank you!

Here is the visual representation of my Firestore.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're trying to fetch data from a sub-collection (posts) within a specific document (user_uids) in your user_activities collection. The FirestoreHelper.readAll method you've defined is intended to fetch all documents from a sub-collection, but it might not be structured correctly for your use case.

Based on your Firestore structure, I recommend modifying the FirestoreHelper class to directly target the sub-collection within a specific document. Here's how you can do it:

```
    class FirestoreHelper {
  static Stream<List<UserActivityModel>> readUserPosts(String collectionPath, String userId, String subCollectionPath) {
    final mainCollection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(collectionPath);
    final subcollection = mainCollection
        .doc(userId)
        .collection(subCollectionPath)
        .snapshots();

    return subcollection.map((querySnapshot) => querySnapshot.docs.map((e) => UserActivityModel.fromSnapshot(e)).toList());
  }
}
```

Then, you can use the modified function in your StreamBuilder:

```
    StreamBuilder<List<UserActivityModel>>(
  stream: FirestoreHelper.readUserPosts("user_activities", "user_uids", "posts"),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
      return const Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
      );
    } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
      return const Center(
        child: Text("An error has occured while fetching users posts."),
      );
    } else if (snapshot.data!.isEmpty) {
      print("snapshot.data: ${snapshot.data?.length}");
      return Container(
        color: Colors.white,
        child: const Center(
          child: Text(
            "No posts/images posted by users...",
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          ),
        ),
      );
    } else {
      // Apply the code to handle the data
      // You can access the data using `snapshot.data`
    }
  }
)
```

Make sure you replace "user_uids" with the actual user UID you want to fetch posts for.